# How to simplify this lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have this class which contains int array

```
 public class Combination
 {
    public int[] CombinationSet { get; set; }
 }
```

There is static List with many instances of this class

```
public static List<Combination> Combinations = new List<Combination>();
```

Now I need methods to find combinations on that list so far I have

For 2

```
 public static List<Combination> FindCombinations(int x,int y)
    {
        if (x == y)
        {
            return Combinations.Where(
           lenght => lenght.CombinationSet.Length == 2)
           .Where( 
                data => (data.CombinationSet[0] == x && data.CombinationSet[1] == y)
               || (data.CombinationSet[1] == x && data.CombinationSet[0] == y)
               ).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return Combinations.Where(
          lenght => lenght.CombinationSet.Length == 2)
          .Where(data => data.CombinationSet.Contains(x)
          && data.CombinationSet.Contains(y)
          ).ToList();
        }

    }
```

**Example :** 
if list contains sets : { 1 , 2} , { 1, 3} , { 1 , 2}

and you would call FindCombination(1,2), you would get back list with two instances

It is working fine however for 4 parameters it would be over 24 rows in else statement. I need maximum of 4 I just wonder if there is some more clever way of doing this.

for 3 it looks like this

```
 public static List<Combination> FindCombinations(int x, int y,int z)
    {
        if(x == y || x == z || y == z)
        {
            return Combinations.Where(
            lenght =>
            lenght.CombinationSet.Length == 3).
            Where(
                inner => ( (
                    inner.CombinationSet[0] == x && inner.CombinationSet[1] == y && inner.CombinationSet[2] == z)
                || (inner.CombinationSet[0] == x && inner.CombinationSet[2] == y && inner.CombinationSet[1] == z)
                || (inner.CombinationSet[1] == x && inner.CombinationSet[0] == y && inner.CombinationSet[2] == z)
                || (inner.CombinationSet[1] == x && inner.CombinationSet[2] == y && inner.CombinationSet[0] == z)
                || (inner.CombinationSet[2] == x && inner.CombinationSet[0] == y && inner.CombinationSet[1] == z)
                || (inner.CombinationSet[2] == x && inner.CombinationSet[1] == y && inner.CombinationSet[0] == z)
                )).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return Combinations.Where(
            length =>
            length.CombinationSet.Length == 3
            ).Where(data => data.CombinationSet.Contains(x)
            && data.CombinationSet.Contains(y)
            && data.CombinationSet.Contains(z)
            ).ToList();
        }

    }
```

Comment: So, I take that you would like a `FindCombinations` method that takes in an array of combination, not just x, y or z if its for 3

Comment: I have a question for your requirements, can you ask for a combination with more numbers than those in CombinationSet? I mean, can you search for {1, 2, 3} when the arrays only contain {1, 2} or {1, 3} for example? Or this doesn't matter?

Comment: you can ask for doubles triples and quadros. There are different overloads for each case. As for the list itself it can contain array of any length.

Comment: So, you cannot actually have a generic input for the method? Or can you?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the question, you want this method to return a list of all the Combinations where the CombinationSet contains all the ints you pass into the method? What if the CombinationSet contains extra ints as well, will you return these as well?

Comment: When `x=y` then all you need is `Where(data => data.CombinationSet.All(z => z == x))` since you only expect to have 2 values anyway.  This of course doesn't work as well when you have more than 2 values.

Comment: @Mayhem I could have.

Comment: @Zohar yes. any array longer then number of parameters will be excluded in that particular method.

Comment: For clarification, does the Lengths of the list matter?  Does the Order matter?  If *no* for both of those, then I just need to make sure that all the items I pass exist at least once in the combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, then just check if all three values are present in the array (don't worry about using an index to check the position of each integer):

```
return Combinations.Where(c => c.CombinationSet.Contains(x) 
    && c.CombinationSet.Contains(y) 
    && c.CombinationSet.Contains(z));
```

If it must have exactly the number of elements that were passed in, you could add additional AND statements to match the array length, etc.

EDIT: Based on your comment, what if you ordered the integers before comparing, and then returned the Combination only if the ordered sets are identical.  This should work as long as the combination must contain the same number of elements that are passed in:

```
return Combinations.Where(c => c.CombinationSet.OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(new int[] { x, y, z }.OrderBy(j => j)));
```

Comment: No this doesnt work, that I had before this. It leads to returning (1,2) set when you call FindCombination(2,2)

Comment: Are you sure about that? Must have been a typo because this should only return combinationSets that contains x, y and z.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - 2 and 2 both exist in the set (1,2) - that's what Universus is getting at... I have revised my answer.

Comment: tryed this for duos :         return Combinations.
            Where(length => length.CombinationSet.Length == 2).
            Where(c => c.CombinationSet.OrderBy(i => i) == new int[] { x, y }.
            OrderBy(j => j)).
            ToList();
doesnt work

Comment: @Universus - see my edit.  I changed the `==` to `.SequenceEqual(...)` and tested this.  x = 1 and y = 2 matches [1, 2] and [2, 1] but not [3, 4] or [2, 2] or [1, 2, 3].

Comment: Good it is working, my only concern now is speed. I pretty sure Contains is fast like almost O(1) but ordering all sequences, I am not so sure about it.

Comment: By ordering the sequences first, you can then make 1 comparison instead of a whole bunch like your original method... you can compare the performance in a loop if you’re worried, but unless you have a huge data set I think you’ll be ok. If you want to optimize the comparison, you could store the ordered array as a separate property in the Comparison class - set it automatically in the setter for CombinationSet. Then you only have to do the ordering once per Combination and not every time you run the method. That seems like overkill to me, though.

Comment: I will keep that in mind when checking for performance. Well I expect to have about 1000 Combinations but it has to run on every potato Android so yeah you can never have enought performance. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have an object that contains the the list, you may want to put the logic directly on the object.  Although really there is no reason (you've provided) to use an array, so might as well make it a List.

```
public class Combination
{
    public List<int> CombinationSet { get; set; }

    public bool IsSequenceEqual(params int[] values)
    {
        return CombinationSet.SequenceEqual(values);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", CombinationSet);
    }
}
```

So each Combination doesn't care how many parameters you pass, it just wants to make sure the order and number of items are equal.  So extend this to the function:

```
public static List<Combination> FindCombinations(params int[] values)
{
    var result = _Combinations
        .Where(c => c.IsSequenceEqual(values))
        .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

And [seems to work in a DotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CSW0Bt):

```
public static void Main()
{
    _Combinations.Add(new Combination{ CombinationSet = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3}});
    _Combinations.Add(new Combination{ CombinationSet = new List<int>{ 2, 3, 4}});
    _Combinations.Add(new Combination{ CombinationSet = new List<int>{ 3, 2, 1}});
    _Combinations.Add(new Combination{ CombinationSet = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3}});

    Console.WriteLine("Test 1  (1,2,3)");
    foreach(var result in FindCombinations(1,2,3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Test 1  (3,2,1)");
    foreach(var result in FindCombinations(3,2,1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Test 1  (1,2)");
    foreach(var result in FindCombinations(1,2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

resulting in:

> Test 1  (1,2,3)
>
> 1, 2, 3
>
> 1, 2, 3
>
> Test 1  (3,2,1)
>
> 3, 2, 1
>
> Test 1  (1,2)

Comment: Good idea however Test1 should return 123 123 321. As I said I care about instances of Combination not CombinationSequence itself.

Comment: Would you like me to update it to handle that?  Pretty easy